# Passing a closure as a parameter to a constructor c++

Tags: c++, c++11, closures, functor

In the code below, I'd like to get rid of the weird constructors taking various types of function pointers, and the parameter lists that have to be saved off (along with all the member variables that are required to hold all this), and instead use a closure to do all of that, leaving Event with a single member variable that is something like `Closure closure;`. Is there a way to do this using closures in C++0x?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

class Event
{
    std::function<double(double, double)> func1;
    bool func1Defined;
    double double1, double2;

    std::function<double(int, int, int)> func2;
    bool func2Defined;
    int int1, int2, int3;
public:
    void setFalse()
    {
        func1Defined = false;
        func2Defined = false;
    }
    Event(std::function<double(double, double)> func, double double1, double double2)
    {
        setFalse();
        func1 = func;
        func1Defined = true;
        this->double1 = double1;
        this->double2 = double2;
    }

    Event(std::function<double(int, int, int)> func, int int1, int int2, int int3)
    {
        setFalse();
        func2 = func;
        func2Defined = true;
        this->int1 = int1;
        this->int2 = int2;
        this->int3 = int3;
    }

    void run()
    {
        double ret = 0;
        if (func1Defined) ret = func1(double1, double2);
        else if (func2Defined) ret = func2(int1, int2, int3);
        /* do something with ret */
        std::cout << ret << "\n";
    }
};

double twoDoubleParam(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double threeIntParam(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return (a + b) / c;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::list<Event> events;
    events.push_back(Event(*twoDoubleParam, 1.0, 3.5));
    events.push_back(Event(*threeIntParam, 2, 4, 2));
    std::for_each(events.begin(), events.end(), [&](Event event)
    {
        event.run();
    });

    int y;
    std::cin >> y;
    return 0;
}
```

Prefer no boost, but if boost is best/only easy way to do this I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `Event` should just hold a `std::function<double()>` in the first place: independent on using lambda or not, you want to bind the arguments to create a nullary function (as far as I can tell; if there are actual parameters to each call, you'd obviously use a corresponding signature in `std::function<Signature>`.

Assuming you `Event` has a member `fun` of type `std::function<double()>` and a constructor like

```
template <typename Fun>
Event::Event(Fun fun): fun(fun) {}
```

you could, e.g., use

```
events.emplace_back([](){ return twoDoubleParam(1.0, 3.5); });
events.emplace_back(std::bind(&threeIntParam, 2, 4, 2));
```

Both approaches could use `std::bind()` or lambda. I just mixed the use to get one of each. Obviously, if you use the lambda and the parameters are not constants but rather values, you'd use `[=](){ ... }` to capture the closure values by value.

Comment: This works very well. Thank you everyone for your helpful responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::bind` and `std::function` :

```
class Event {
    function<double()> func;
public:
    template <typename H, typename... Args>
    Event(H &&f, Args&&... args) 
          : func(bind(std::forward<H>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}

    void run()
    {
        double ret = func();
        std::cout << ret << "\n";
    }
};

double twoDoubleParam(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}

double threeIntParam(int a, int b, int c) {
    return (a + b) / c;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::list<Event> events;
    events.push_back(Event(twoDoubleParam, 1.0, 3.5));
    events.push_back(Event(threeIntParam, 2, 4, 2));
    std::for_each(events.begin(), events.end(), [&](Event &event)
    {
        event.run();
    });
}
```

Output

```
4.5
3
```

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41666abb72ea82c5)

Comment: I like the look of this, but it doesn't compile for me in MSVS any tips? Noteably the line with ... gives me: error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'

Comment: @Josh: It compiles for gcc. What's your MSVS version? What error do you see?

Comment: I'm using MSVS 2012,  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...' is the important error

Comment: Did you include `<functional>` and `<algorithm>` and write `using namespace std;` ? The live code has them.

Comment: Yes, I have both functional and algorithm, using namespace std;
errors:
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Args'
error C2660: 'Event::Event' : function does not take 3 arguments
error C2660: 'Event::Event' : function does not take 4 arguments

Comment: It seems MSVC-2012 doesn't support variadic templates. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::bind` to do this.  See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

It's in VS2012/13, and the newer GCC as well.  The return value can be assigned directly to a `std::function<void()>` if you want as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `std::bind`:

```
std::function<void()> func;

...

Event(std::function<double(double, double)> func, double d1, double d2) {
    func = std::bind(func, d1, d2);
}

// Repeat for the three ints
```

Alternatively you can just have the user be able to give any functor/args combo and bind it for them, like the constructor of `std::thread`:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
Event(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

or

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
Event(Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) > 1, "Event() requires more than 1 argument");
    func = std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```