# serialize std::function with variable parameters

Tags: c++, templates, closures, functor, std-function

my question is somewhat related to this question: [Serialize C++ functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771842/serialize-c-functor), but still different. It is a followup to this question: [Passing a closure as a parameter to a constructor c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939889/passing-a-closure-as-a-parameter-to-a-constructor-c)

Basically I have code that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Event
{
public:
    std::function<double()> func;
    template <typename T>
    Event(T func): func(func) {}
    virtual double execute()
    {
        double endtime = func();
        return endtime;
    }
};

double foo(int v1, int v2)
{
    return(v1/(v2 * 1.0));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    Event* e = new Event([=]() -> double{return foo(a, b);});
    cout << e->execute() << endl;
    int y;
    std::cin >> y;
}
```

Is there a way to serialize func? I'd like to be able to save and load the function pointer AND the values to the parameters that the function it points to needs. 
the output of the above is:

```
0.75
```

I'm using MSVS 2012, but would consider changing to MSVS 2013 if an answer requires features only available in the latter.

Comment: where and how do you use sizeof(func)/sizeof(this->func) ? Some code would help to answer this mystery.

Comment: Within the constructor, `sizeof(func) == sizeof(T)` (referring to the argument), while `sizeof(this->func) == sizeof(std::function<double()>)` (referring to the class member). In this instantiation, `T` is the type of the lambda.

Comment: cool, thank you for that explanation. Do you happen to also know how to save and load this thing?

Comment: by serialize you mean you want to make `std::function` to some byte array? I can't image how could this possibly be done.